# How to take off 10% off every element in a list [Python]?

Tags: python, list, percentage

This is my code so far, it takes input from a user and stores them as a list, I'm stuck what the next line of code should be.

```
numbers = []
numbers = list(map(int,input("Please enter your numbers seperated by a space:").split()))

lengthOfList = len(numbers)

for i in range(len(numbers)):
```

Answer (score 3):

```
result = [.9*x for x in numbers]
```

I guess this is what you want. You could do everything in one line as you can rewrite the input line as:

```
numbers = [int(k) for k in input("Please enter your numbers seperated by a space:").split()]
```

Comment: For one line solution, it should be `numbers = [0.9*int(k) for k in .....]`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by just multiplying each number by `0.9`

```
numbers = []
numbers = list(map(int,input("Please enter your numbers seperated by a space:").split()))
new_numbers=[num*0.9 for num in numbers]
print(new_numbers)
```

You can also do same like below

```
new_numbers=[]
for num in numbers:
    new_numbers.append(num*0.9)

print(new_numbers)
```

Comment: No, that's not what 10% **off** means. You should multiply by 0.9, not 0.1.

Comment: It all depends on "of" vs "off"! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it using the [`map`](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html#map) function:

```
numbers = []
numbers = list(map(int,input("Please enter your numbers seperated by a space:").split()))
numbers = list(map(lambda elem: 0.9 * elem, numbers))
print(numbers)
```